# Python in OS X: Detect multiple monitors and move application window to specific monitor

Tags: python, macos, monitor, pyobjc, appleevents

**Question**: Is there a way to have Python detect when running the code in OS X, if there is more than one monitor active? Is it then, possible to move a specific OS X application window to one of those monitors by choosing?

---

*FYI:* I have previously been able to utilize `Carbon` to activate a specific application window as seen in the code below. I'm not aware if it has the capabilities sought above.

```
from Carbon import AppleEvents
from Carbon import AE

window_target = AE.AECreateDesc(AppleEvents.typeApplicationBundleID, "org.mozilla.FireFox")
window_activate = AE.AECreateAppleEvent('misc', 'actv', window_target, AppleEvents.kAutoGenerateReturnID, AppleEvents.kAnyTransactionID)
window_activate.AESend(AppleEvents.kAEWaitReply, AppleEvents.kAENormalPriority, AppleEvents.kAEDefaultTimeout)
```

Comment: You can do this with PyObjC. Carbon is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

To detect monitors, you can use [`NSScreen.screens()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSScreen/screens). You can then probably just position your `NSWindow` within the destination `NSScreen`'s `visibleFrame`.

At least that would work with your own application windows -- I'm not sure about how to move a different application's window(s) or if it's even possible via the Cocoa API.

For that particular use case, one possible approach is to use AppleScript instead (e.g., [Moving finder window from one display to another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136324/moving-finder-window-from-one-display-to-another) or [Positioning a window with AppleScript using dual monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865989/positioning-a-window-with-applescript-using-dual-monitors)).